WorkFlows - Multiple IF-Else condition
I am trying to set a field based on multiple if-else conditions in a workflow.
eg:
Set Field1 = 1, if Condition x is Yes ,
ELSE
Set Field1 = 2, if Condition y is Yes & Condition Z=yes,
ELSE
Set Field1 = 3, if Condition a is Yes & Condition b=yes etc.
Is it possible to achieve through a workflow? Or should I use a Workflow Action script or a User Event script. Please advice.

You can use the Formula field to set a conditional value in a Set Field Value action.  Use SQL formulas for server side triggers and JavaScript triggers (including SS1.0 API functions) for client side triggers.
